# Any painless way to trigger the soft keyboard for EditText in dialogs?

Tags: android, dialog

I am rendering an `EditText` as one element of a list-style `AlertDialog` (which is backed by the default `ListView` implementation). I sort of expected that this circumstance would not change the behavior of EditText, but it does: a click on the EditText does not spawn the soft keyboard anymore.

After an hour of messing around with focus settings and click handlers I got fed up and debugged into `InputMethodManager.showSoftInput()`, and found this:

```
    public boolean showSoftInput(View view, int flags,
        ResultReceiver resultReceiver) {
        ...
        if (mServedView != view && (mServedView == null
                || !mServedView.checkInputConnectionProxy(view))) {
            return false;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem here is that `mServedView` is the ListView that's backing the dialog, while `view` is the EditText, and `ListView.checkInputConnectionProxy()` does simply `return false` in the default implementation of ListView (to be overridden by subclasses).

Worse, I couldn't find a way to set a custom ListView which allows proxying IME requests; `AlertDialog.Builder.setView()` accepts a custom ListView, but this is not the ListView that InputMethodManager sees.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this, apologies if you have

```
getBaseContext().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Frankly, I don't remember :-) I'm not working on that project ATM, but I'll have another look by then. Thanks for the idea anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

let me preface this with a big fat I KNOW NOTHING ABOUT THE ANDROID SDK.

That being said I would suggest:
write a requestKeyboard throwable.
have your EditText throw the requestKeyboard.
This way the ListView can handle the throwable, generate the keyboard, then return the input to the edit text.
This way mServedView == view

I think.

Comment: wicked idea, but I'm pretty sure that throwing anything inside a onFocus/onClick handler will simply terminate your app.